# how to print resource to string (struts java)

Tags: java, resources, struts

suppose the following code:

```
ActionMessages errors = f.validate(mapping, request);
Iterator<ActionMessage> iter = errors.get();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    output.append(iter.next()+"<br />");
}
```

if the actionMessage points to a resource, how could I grab the string in the resource instead of printing the key?

Comment: I don't get it. What's the purpose of the code above, and is it written inside a JSP?

Comment: No. Perhaps you should go answer a question you have a knowledge of instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if `isResource()` returns `true`, and if so, call [`getResources()`](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html#getResources%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) and use the resulting [`MessageResources`](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/util/MessageResources.html) instance to formate the message with its resource key and its values.

Note that action messages are typically displayed from a JSP, and that the JSP should use the struts errors and messages tags to display the messages.

Comment: Yes I know usually it would be in a JSP, but part of a page I am refactoring to use ajax, so I need to be able to display the errors without reloading the whole page.

Comment: Your Java method generates HTML. So it could very well be a standard Struts action which forwards to a JSP containing just the snippet of HTML to return from the AJAX call. Every JSP doesn't need to be a full HTML page.

Comment: Cheers. That made me think. I may be able to create a JSPF and include that in my page.